# MX record (out of zone) has no addresses records (A or AAAA)

Tags: email, dns, bind

I have a problem with my zone config file, I hope someone can help me.
I am trying to add MX record for a subdomain that we use for Microsoft 365 ecosystem

I entered an MX record that was given to me by MS:

```
subdomain 3600 IN MX 0 **.mail.protection.outlook.com.
```

But i get the error:

> zone **/IN: **/MX '**.mail.protection.outlook.com' (out of zone) has no addresses records (A or AAAA)

I cant enter an A record since i don't have the value for it. how do i Solve this?

i deleted all the company data and put stars in it, but you get the gist of it

Comment: Hm? Hopefully you didn’t literally put `**` in the zone file. You should’ve received a regular hostname like `my-company.mail.protection‌.outlook.com.`.

Comment: no i did not put * in zone file, i just replaced company name with stars :)

Comment: [maybe this will help on answers Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_domains/no-a-record-for-mx-record/fb4f3e74-3b17-4752-9c72-9247d716a6ee)